# Tiva C series with nRF24L01+ SPI always returns the STATUS register

Tags: embedded, spi

I have encountered a problem very similar to this post: [TIva C Series problems with I2C Interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23404535/tiva-c-series-problems-with-i2c-interface)

I am using Energia to program a Tiva C Series TI Launchpad (TM4C123 processor) via SPI. I want to send data using a nRFL01+ chip, but whenever I try to read the registers, it returns the default `STATUS` register.

I know that this register information is sent at the beginning of every SPI transaction with the nRF24L01+, so my initial guess was that there was a problem with my `MISO`/`MOSI` configuration. To debug this, i plugged my `MISO` and `MOSI` together and received the expected pinged data everytime.

As to test for problems with `SCK` or `CSN` pins, as far as I know, I need an oscilloscope, which I don't have.

Do you think it's a software problem with Energia?

Comment: Programming SPI drivers without having an oscilloscope is not very sensible. Kind of like writing source code without having a computer screen to look at :) SPI is quite poorly standardized: most notably, the slave select mechanism and clock sync/clock phase settings tend to differ on every single device. On top of that, SPI also tends to be prone to EMI issues at higher speeds. So you _must_ check the signal with a scope at some point and validate it. Otherwise you are very likely to get sudden bugs and problems when the product is out in production. Been there, done that.

Answer (score 3):

I actually have found how to fix my problem before posting the question, but I figured it could be helpful to others so I posted it anyway and i'll write how I fixed it.

Basically, I think the `CSN` pin is switched low then high for each byte transmitted, even though the nRF24L01+ chip needs it to stay low for multiple bytes to properly transmit the information. Instead of using the default `CSN` pin, I used another one at random and switched it myself before and after transmitting my bytes.

I think it's an issue with the `SPI.transfer` routine in Energia, although I have not found it (might be very interesting to look deeper into the SPI library to propose a patch to Energia, but this is too complex for me at the moment).

Comment: You should read the reference manual (or user guide) of the MCU. There might be a config-bit in the SPI module which changes nSS behaviour between TI and Motorola (sic!) mode. It might also be impossible to have this behaviour automatically, so you have to handle that signal manually. However, does the MCU not allow to use the same pin for that (GPIO function)?

Comment: I thought that SPI communications relied on the nSS/CSN pin to stay low during the whole transaction, whatever the mode or the chip you are talking to. If this is true, then I guess there's no doubt that there's a bug in the code.
I checked the pin mapping (http://energia.nu/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/tm4c123pinmap.png) and it shows that there are many I2C and UART pins that are sometimes multiplexed with the SPI pins, so it might the source of the bug.
To answer your question, I did try to manually switch the dedicated CSN pin before choosing a random pin.

Comment: Aah, before reading this answer I already wrote in my comment above: _"most notably, the slave select mechanism...  tend to differ on every single device"_. This issue you are having is classic for SPI. Unlike for UART, CAN etc, there is no SPI standard telling how this should behave! (Not even the name SPI is standardized.) There's usually an automatic setting in the SPI hardware, which pulls the select line low only during clock-out. But some devices need to have the select line pulled down longer than that, in which case you have to toggle it manually.

Comment: Thanks to the both of you! This have been very helpful!